# Get original url from J2EE Security Forward

Tags: jsf

I am using Container security (J2EE Security) in a PrimeFaces application and I cannot get the originally requested URL. After the user is authenticated, I want to direct them back to their original request. I cannot find that original request anywhere.

J2EE security provider is configured in Weblogic and form authentication is in the web XML like this:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/faces/unauthorized.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

In the login form, I do the authentication inside the bean. Imagine a simple form as such:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText id="userName" value="#{userManager.userName}" />
    <p:password id="password" value="#{userManager.password}"/>
    <p:commandButton action="#{userManager.login()}" value="Login"/>
</h:form>
```

Login Bean would look like this:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserManager implements Serializable {
private String userName;
private String password;
private String requestedURL;

@Inject
private HttpServletRequest request;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    requestedURL = request.getHeader("Referer"); //this is null

    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String forwardRequestURI = (String)externalContext.getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);       
}
public void login() {
    request.login(getUserName(), getPassword());
    //if successful, redirect back to place they came from
}    
}
```

Both request.getHeader("Referer") and the RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI are null. What is the magic I need here?

Comment: Don't build your own security/authentication framework. Use an existing one. Shiro, Picketlink, whatver. They all have this build-in. And maybe they are null... Did you inspect the request via a breakpoint? If they are null, JSF cannot help this, the servlet container should do this. But see my remark at the start of the comment

Comment: @Kukeltje, don't you remember trying to help me with Shiro? It was a mess. Container security does exactly what I need. It integrates with AD and even does single signon across the realm. We even have support. Plus, I believe they will continue to improve it. So... How can I get that URL? Has to be a trick to it.

Comment: Sorry, no I don't. I (try to) help dozens of people a week. But read the rest of my comment. The container should provide it. If it does not, JSF cannot access it.  And maybe check if it is present in the rendering of the login page (via debugging the request in the  prerender bean). If so store it somewhere to be used. If it gets lost in the redirect to the login page, blame the spec or file a bug with the container (if the spec says it should be kept). As it stands, JSF is not to blame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Weblogic, use:

```
String targetUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("weblogic.formauth.targeturl");
```

Comment: I doubt it was the intention of a JavaEE security standard to require weblogic specific code. If you look at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-javaee8-security-api-2/index.html you see a JSF example. Might be that you approach the 'redirect' back in the wrong way and the container should do this for you (which would be the more logical way)

Comment: That article is EE 8 and we are not there yet. From what I read, it all gets a little easier with EE 8. Another reason we chose it.

Comment: So Are you sure you are using javaee security (EE7?) or some weblogic specific things?

Comment: We just started using EE security and it is at EE7